# Output formatting

Tags: c, format, printf

[image: output]
How do I make the output in w way so every column would be aligned?
My current formatting is:

```
        printf("Posting #%d,  Timestamp: %d,  Light: %d,  Temperature: %d,  Humidity:  %d\n", i, valArr[i][j], valArr[i][j+1], valArr[i][j+2], valArr[i][j+3]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%2d` in your `printf` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the first answer to the question, `%2d` will print an integer two characters wide, `%3d` will print a decimal integers, at least 3 characters wide.

There's also other formatting options in `printf` for floating point variables and octal/hex, for example:

`%6f` will print as floating point, at least 6 characters wide.

`%.2f` will print as floating point, 2 characters after the point.

You can omit either one from the statement, it's still valid. Simply the width will not be constrained.